# How many zeros are there in $25!$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How many zeros are there in $25!$?

I don't know how to really calculate it the number of zeros in the right hand can easily find by [Legendre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula).

That gives us:

$\lfloor{\frac{25}{5}}\rfloor+\lfloor{\frac{25}{25}}\rfloor=5+1=6$

But I got stuck with finding the zeros between.Any hints?

Comment: Not following...you have correctly observed that $v_5(25!)=6$.  As $v_2(25!)$ is certainly bigger than that, the answer must be $6$.  Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: You need to count *all* the zeros, not just the ones at the end?

Comment: I think the mean counting the number of 0's in the string $25!= 15511210043330985984000000$.

Comment: @T.Bongers  Yikes!  You think?  I doubt there is a good general way of doing that...though, as you point out, this particular case is fairly easy to handle directly.

Comment: @lulu You should find all the zeros not just the end zeros.

Comment: @TahaAkbari  Got it.  That sounds hard.  Wolfram alpha (or other sources) can certainly handle the raw computation....don't see a more elegant way to proceed.

Comment: @TahaAkbari This is easy to do numerically, but I don't know of any nice patterns. For example, $1000!$ is a 2568 digit number in which zero occurs 472 times. (Computed in a few milliseconds in python)

Comment: This depends on base-10 arithmetic coincidences, so I doubt that there is any reasonable formula. I could not find this in OEIS.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Your question was how many. No one has come up with a better way than evaluating 25! explicitly and counting the zeros, so please accept the CW answer below if you are content, or explain why you are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

25!=15511210043330985984000000, so the answer is 9 zeros. [Thanks to @T.Bongers]

Or:

```
def fact(n):
  if n < 2:
    return 1
  else:
    return n*fact(n-1)

print str(fact(25)).count('0')
```

Thanks to Python.

Comment: Depending on the system, this will break once $n$ is large because the recursion limit will be hit. I'd suggest a loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your calculation gives the ended zeroes but for the other appearing in the decimal expression of $25!$ I think you have no other way that to get a such expression.  The calculator of Windows gives
$$15\space 511\space 210\space 043\space 330\space 985\space 984\space 000\space 000$$ hence you have $6+3=\color{red}{9}$